# DNS does not resolve after VPN

Tags: vpn, dns, ping, routing, nslookup

1. connected remote vpn(random vpn provider)          --OK Internet access
2. add to route tables 10.0.0.0/8(lan) to go trough local network gateway
3. ping localnetworkcomputer with ip (10.10.74.48)    --OK response
4. ping localnetworkcomputer with name (localpc)      --FAIL hot not found
5. ping localdnsserver with ip (10.10.74.253)         --OK response
6. nslookup localpc 10.10.74.253                      --FAIL FAILSRV

--when not connected to the remote vpn all this steps are OK.

How i can resolve local network names with internal DNS Server while connected to VPN?

Comment: What dnsserver is your nslookup using?

Comment: Is an internal dns server, in a windows domain

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN, what server does nslookup report as using. Also, what do you get if you do nslookup 10.10.74.48 10.10.74.253 or if you use the fully qualified domain name?

Answer (score 2):

If your VPN client adds an additional network interface to your system, you may have to go into the TCP/IP properties of that interface to set your local DNS server manually there. When you type `nslookup` by itself, it should show you what server it is using to do the lookups.

Comment: If i do that happens the same as in step 6, the dns do not resolver local lan hosts, it resolve external like google.com

Answer (score 0):

Your VPN connection profile may have "split tunneling" disabled. This means you will not be able to access resources on your local network while you are connected to the VPN. (That you are able to ping local IPs at all is a little surprising though, if this is the case.) This is a security configuration which should not be tampered with if you do not own the system or the remote network.